# Undeclared variable in just one function

Tags: c, struct

So I have a struct that I'm declaring in a function and whenever I try running the program it says that the variable is undeclared. However, that error only appears in that function and it doesn't appear in any other function when I declare that struct.

https://repl.it/@JeevenMann/RelevantWetInverse#main.c

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
  typedef struct wordStruct {
    char *charPointer;
    int numChars;
    int wordPos;
    struct wordStruct *nextWord;
  } word;

typedef struct sentenceStruct{
  word *wordObj;
  int lineNum;
  int wordCount;
  struct sentenceStruct *nextSentence;
} sentence;

typedef struct linkedStructure {
  sentence *firstSentence;
  int sentenceNum;

} LIST;



void printOut(LIST * sentenceList) {
  //Declare variables for sentenceIndex
  int sentenceIndex = 0;


  //reset sentence Index and print out all words on each line
  sentenceIndex = 0;
  sentence *currentSentence = sentenceList->firstSentence;
  printf("\n\nThis is all the words printed out on the same line as entered:\n");
  while (currentSentence != NULL) {
    word *currentWord = currentSentence->wordObj;
    int wordIndex = 0;
    while (currentWord != NULL) {
      printf("%s ", currentWord->charPointer);

      currentWord = currentWord->nextWord;
    }



    printf("\n");
    currentSentence = currentSentence->nextSentence;
  }
}


void storeWords(sentence * sentenceObj, char line[]) {
//Declare count variables and index variables
int index = 0;
int wordCount = 1;
int charCount = 1;
word* currentWord;
char copyWord[1000];
//Delegate memory to wordObject and char array
sentenceObj -> wordObj = (word * ) malloc(sizeof(word));
currentWord = sentenceObj->wordObj;
// Loop though sentence until we reach EOS char
while (line[index] != '\n') {

  //check if array index is not a space
  if (line[index] != ' ') {
    //set char to current index
    //increase char count
    //realloc more memory to char pointers
    copyWord[charCount - 1] = line[index];
    charCount++;

    //if the next index is a EOS symbol or an empty space
    if (line[index + 1] == '\n' || line[index + 1] == ' ') {
      sentenceObj -> wordCount = wordCount;
      currentWord->numChars = charCount - 1;
      currentWord->wordPos = wordCount;
      copyWord[charCount-1] = '\0';
      currentWord->charPointer = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(char) * charCount);
      strcpy(currentWord->charPointer,copyWord);



      if (line[index + 1] == ' ') {
        wordCount++;
        charCount = 1;

        currentWord->nextWord = (word * ) malloc(sizeof(word));
        currentWord = currentWord->nextWord;
        currentWord->nextWord = NULL;
        strcpy(copyWord,"");
      }
    }

  }

  index++;

}

}
LIST * readInput() {
//declare variables for str and lineNum
char str[1000] = "";
int lineNum = 1;
LIST *sentenceList = (LIST *) calloc(1,sizeof(LIST));
  sentence *currentSentence;
  sentenceList->firstSentence = (sentence * ) calloc(1, sizeof(sentence));
  currentSentence = sentenceList->firstSentence;
//while the user doesn't enter an empty string, continue
printf("Enter a string: ");

  fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
  printf("%s\n",str );


while (strcmp(str, "\n") != 0){

  //user hasn't entered an empty string so allocate more memory and populate
  //the struct
    currentSentence->lineNum = lineNum;
    storeWords(currentSentence, str);
        lineNum = lineNum + 1;

        printf("Enter a string: ");
        fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
        printf("%s\n",str );

    if (strcmp(str, "\n") != 0) {
      currentSentence->nextSentence =  (sentence * ) calloc(1, sizeof(sentence));
      currentSentence = currentSentence->nextSentence;
      currentSentence->nextSentence = NULL;
    }
  }

//print out the sentence as defined by assignment
printOut(sentenceList);
return sentenceList;

}

int searchSentences(LIST * sentenceList, char word[]) {
  //Declare variables for the sentence index and return int boolean if word is found
  int sentenceIndex = 0;
  int wordFound = 0;


  //loop through sentenceObjects and print out if that word matches word to find
  sentence *currentSentence = sentenceList->firstSentence;
  printf("\n\nThis is all the words printed out on the same line as entered:\n");
  while (currentSentence != NULL) {
    word *theWord = currentSentence->wordObj;
    int wordIndex = 0;
    while (theWord != NULL) {
      if (strcmp(theWord->charPointer,word) == 0) {
        printf("%s found in line %d position %d\n", word, currentSentence->lineNum, theWord.wordPos);
        wordFound = 1;
      }
      theWord = theWord->nextWord;
    }



    printf("\n");
    currentSentence = currentSentence->nextSentence;
  }

  return wordFound;
}

void findString(LIST * sentenceList) {
  //declare char array
  char str[1000];

  //while the user doesn't enter an empty string continue to search for the word
  do {

    printf("\n\nEnter a word to search for:\n");
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
    str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';

    if (strcmp(str, "") != 0 && searchSentences(sentenceList, str) == 0) {
      printf("%s was not found in this file\n", str);
    }

  } while (strcmp(str, "") != 0);

}

int main() {
  //Declare line objects
  LIST *sentenceList;


  //get Number of lines and ask user for info
  sentenceList = readInput();
  findString(sentenceList);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks, I've been trying to fix this for a while now, but I can't seem to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Please, copy the relevant code to the question, instead of linking an external source.

Comment: What is the variable that is undeclared? And, what is the exact error message?

Comment: It's harder to understand your question because you are not using standard terminology. You're not trying to declare the struct. You're trying to declare a variable whose type is a pointer to struct. However, `word` is not a struct in the error case. You have a parameter called `word` that is shadowing it: "main.c:142:51: warning: declaration of ‘word’ shadows a global declaration [-Wshadow]
     int searchSentences(LIST * sentenceList, char word[]) {"

Comment: @RaymondChen Could you post what you said as a response so I can checkmark it. The issue was with that parameter called word and the struct called word. Thanks a ton.

Comment: In `searchSentences`, you have an argument: `char word[]`. But, above, `word` is a `typedef`. Later, in the same function, you try to declare `word *theWord`. So, this is a conflict. Change the arg to something else (e.g.) `char wordbuf[]` and adjust other places to match.

Comment: You can post your own answer and accept it. I don't need the imaginary points.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconverson -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same list of problems.

Comment: OT: regarding: `LIST *sentenceList = (LIST *) calloc(1,sizeof(LIST));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing the cast.  2) the function: `calloc()` can fail!  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  if not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "calloc failed" ) to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  This error is not recoverable, so then cleanup and call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: the posted code calls `calloc()` but fails to (before exiting)  pass such pointers to `free()`  The result is a memory leak.

Comment: OT:  the indent width of only 2 spaces can 'disappear' when using variable width fonts.  Strongly suggest each indent level be 4 spaces for readability and visibility of code structure

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: (the compiler does not care) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.   Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: OT:  regarding; `fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
    str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';`   This is very risky because there might not be a '\n' at the end of the string.  Suggest: `str[ strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';` as this will eliminate any trailing '\n' if present and otherwise does nothing to the string.

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of comments: `//declare variables for str and lineNum
char str[1000] = "";
int lineNum = 1;`  This kind of comments that just repeats the code is useless.  Suggest comments that tell `why` or `how`.   As it is, we can all read those two lines of code and know exactly that they are declaring two variables and initializing them.

Comment: OT: the code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E.  1000.  Suggest using `#define` or `enum` statement(s) to give such 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding the function: `LIST * readInput() {`  1) there is not prior prototype, so the signature should be: `LIST * readInput( void ) {`  otherwise the compiler produces code that can take any number of parameters.  2)  the function always results in a uninitialized object (even if it is the first object) at the end of the linked list